# Return to resource route

Tags: laravel, routes

I have below route in my route file.

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'prayer', 'as' => 'prayer.'], function () {
         Route::resource( 'time', 'PrayerTimeController' );
});
```

How can I return to this route from Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly recommend reading through the excellent Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers

To get the route wired up to a controller, update your route resource declaration to use the full class name of the controller:

`Route::resource('time', PrayerTimeController::class);`

Create a controller file: `App\Http\Controllers\PrayerTimeController.php` with this content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PrayerTimeController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    return 'Hello, World!';
  }
}
```

Then import the controller namespace into the routes file you're working in, e.g. `routes/web.php` file:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PrayerTimeController;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'prayer', 'as' => 'prayer.'], function () {
  Route::resource('time', PrayerTimeController::class);
});
```